# Python Requests OAuth2Session() passing multiple scope arguments

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, python-requests

I have successfully authorized an API connection using "data_read" as a scope, however I am having issues passing multiple scope parameters ("data_read" and "data_write") into the OAuth2Session() function.

The parameters for multiple scopes need to be passed into the URL string as

https://api.website.com/oauth20/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=123456&redirect_uri=https...&**scope=data_read&scope=data_write**...

I have tried using a comma delimited list:

`scope=["data_read", "data_write"]`

which results in:

https://api.website.com/oauth20/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=123456&redirect_uri=https...&**scope=data_read+data_write**

I have also tried passing a list of scopes within a dictionary:

```
dict_scope = {'scope':["data_read", "data_write"]}
```

Which results in an error:

```
ValueError: Invalid scope ({'scope': ['data_read', 'data_write']}), must be string, tuple, set, or list.
```

I have reviewed requests documentation here:

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls

here:

http://requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#oauth-2-0-session

and OAuth2 examples here:

http://requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/examples.html#examples

Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Came across the same issue. Pass a space-separated string consisting of multiple scope parameters as mentioned below.

```
scope = "data_read data_write"
```